# Of or At night?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning, difference

Does that mean "at"? Are they interchangeable(of/at)?

Is it possible to replace “of” with “at” here, or does it mean something else?

> On his bench in Madison Square Soapy moved uneasily. When wild geese honk high ***of*** nights, and when women without sealskin coats grow kind to their husbands, and when Soapy moves uneasily on his bench in the park, you may know that winter is near at hand.

Comment: I am curious, what is the source of this quote?

Comment: I find that this is the opening paragraph of ["The Cop and the Anthem" ](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/131/the-four-million/2401/the-cop-and-the-anthem/) by O. Henry. The story dated from 1906, and is full of literary allusions and devices, many of them now somewhat obscure metaphors.

Comment: The Cop and the Anthem O. Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At night" means "during the night time". It is a very common expression. "of nights" means "on a regular basis during the night". It implies something that happens every night or on most nights. "of nights" is a slightly old-fashioned phrase, now used mostly in a literary or poetic context, although perfectly valid and correct.

> - Most people sleep at night.
> - Wolves howl loudly of nights in winter.

The example in the question is quite correct, the phrase "When wild geese honk high of nights"  means that wild geese honk during most or all winter nights. "High" may mean "with a high-pitched sound" or "from high up in the air" -- I can't tell from this example which is intended. Perhaps the author meant both at once. This is the kind of writing where "of nights" is likely to be used.

---

Consider the next to the last stanza of "The Highwayman" by 
Alfred Noyes  (1880–1958 but evoking the feel of a much older time) where the very similar phrase "of a winter’s night" is used.

> And still **of a winter’s night**, they say, when the wind is in the trees,
>
> When the moon is a ghostly galleon tossed upon cloudy seas,
>
> When the road is a ribbon of moonlight over the purple moor,
>
> A highwayman comes riding—
>
> ```
>     Riding—riding—
> ```
>
> A highwayman comes riding, up to the old inn-door.

Comment: I was going to say something similar, but refer to "of nights" as literary and rare. Searching the iWeb corpus for "[verb] of nights" (to eliminate things like "number of nights" and "lot of nights") gives just 46 hits.

Comment: @Colin Fine  Really? I hadn't thought it would be **that** rare. But it is definitely used with a literary intent and style.